# PHP insert blank values instead of GET values

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have this script on my site:

```
<?php

  $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
  $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

  if($db_found) {
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO users (user, address)
    VALUES('".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."')";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    mysql_close($db_handle);
    print "Records added to the database";
  }
  else {
    print "Database NOT found";
    mysql_close($db_handle);
  }
?>
```

I then open this url in my browser:

```
http://ringkapps.altervista.org/addToDatabase.php?user=ringk&address=test
```

But instead of inserting "ringk" and "test" in the table, it inserts this:

[image]

Can't understand why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you do var_dump($_REQUEST), var_dump($_GET) and var_dump($_POST) before your insert? and post results

Comment: `user` != `username`, and there is no password in the GET (and it shouldn't be either, use POST for that!) - and you should hash your passwords!!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: Don't store your passwords in plain-text! This is not secure *at all!* PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function 
which is a lot more secure!

Comment: Your `$_GET` index keys are `user` and `address` not `username` and `password`

Comment: @Qirel yes, this is just a test, i will look at the link you posted, thanks!

Comment: @DiddleDot thanks!

Comment: @RingK If you're just learning MySQL and PHP, I recommend learning the "new" and most secure way first. `mysql_` is like I said, obsolete, so learning it is somewhat a waste of time. Look into PDO or MySQLi, and learn how to use `prepare()` with placeholders ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong!

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO users (user, address)
VALUES('".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."')";
```

Replace this.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO users (user, address)
    VALUES('".$_GET['user']."','".$_GET['address']."')";
```

Comment: It is often a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're calling

```
http://ringkapps.altervista.org/addToDatabase.php?user=ringk&address=test
```

Which creates `$_GET["user"]` and `$_GET["address"]` but you are trying to put in the db `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['password']` which don't exist.

You should call:

```
http://ringkapps.altervista.org/addToDatabase.php?username=ringk&password=test
```

Plus, read something on [security for PHP apps](http://www.ultramegasoft.com/blog/2009/08/5-basic-php-security-tips/), your code is prone to a lot of vulnerabilities!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the url : `http://ringkapps.altervista.org/addToDatabase.php?user=ringk&address=test`

We can see `user = ringk` and `address = test`.
Where user is the key and ringk it's value.
Where address is the key and test it's value.

You can print all the `$_GET` value by using `var_dump($_GET)` and see by yourself what's in it.

My guess is that what you want is to access
`$_GET['user']` and `$_GET['address']`

then just replace the line :

```
 VALUES('".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."')";
```

with

```
 VALUES('".$_GET['user']."','".$_GET['address']."')";
```

or you could update the url to match the code.